# Backreference not working after a pipe

Tags: regex

I have the following data

```
x
xxx
xxxxxxxxx
```

I'm using "g" and "m" flags ((1)not returning on first match and (2)^$ applying to every line).

I want to match the first two rows using a backreference and an alternative (pipe).

This works (but it's not employing a backreference):

```
^(x)$|^xxx$
```

This doesn't work:

```
^(x)$|^\1\1\1$
```

It seems that a pipe creates a new namespace (so to speak) and `\1` doesn't work on the right side of the pipe. Is there any way to avoid such behaviour?

Comment: Yes, it is. (stopgap: comments must be at least 15 characters)

Answer (score 2):

The pipe works as an "or": it either matches the left or the right side. When the right side matches, the left side doesn't so there is nothing to refer back to.

If you want to use a pipe and a back ref you might try this: `^(x)(\1\1|)$`

This matches both "xxx" and "x"

Comment: Is there a way to transfer captured groups between these regexes?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. Either the left side matches and you have a captured group, or the right side matches and you don't have a captured group. If you look at my answer above you'll see another way to write this which first creates a group outside of the "or" and then uses a separate "or" with a back ref to that.

Comment: Well, that technically is using both in the same regex, but not in the same spirit. Very curious if there is a way of transfering backreferences outside of its scope.

Answer (score 1):

`|`means `or`.`regex1|regex2` means match regex1 ..if not try regex2.So when regex1 has not matched how can we backreference it in regex2?

It cannot be backreferenced but can be imitated by a lookahead.

```
(?=^(x))\1*
```

See demo

http://regex101.com/r/hJ7nT4/1

Comment: Is there any way to transfer a captured group to the regex2, then?